# "Are transmitted" vs. "are being transmitted"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, present-participles

> After eight bits are [being] transmitted, D must go high for  at least one bit time, which is referred to as stop bit.

Is "being" required there? Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not required, not even desired. *Are being* is present continuous and means that they are still in the process of being transmitted, but your use of *after* intends to place the reference time for the statement subsequent to their transmission.

Incidentally, my boss likes using the present tense **are** the way you have it;  I prefer **have been** but either works.

You should also add an article in front of *stop bit*-  I like **the** but *a* would not be wrong.